# I need convert this string in Char List

Tags: haskell

I'm learning haskell. I'm reading a string from a text file and need to make this string becomes a list of char.

The input file is this:

```
Individuo A; TACGATCAAAGCT 
Individuo B; AATCGCAT 
Individuo C; TAAATCCGATCAAAGAGAGGACTTA
```

I need convert this string

```
S1 = "AAACCGGTTAAACCCGGGG"  in  S1 = 
["A","A","A","C","C","G","G","T","T","A","A","A","C","C","C","G","G","G","G"] 
or S1 = 
['A','A','A','C','C','G','G','T','T','A','A','A','C','C','C','G','G','G','G']
```

but they are separated by ";"

What should I do?

What can I do?

after getting two lists, I send them to this code:

```
lcsList :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
lcsList [] _ = []
lcsList _ [] = []
lcsList (x:xs) (y:ys) = if x == y
                          then x : lcsList xs ys
                          else
                            let lcs1 = lcsList (x:xs) ys
                                lcs2 = lcsList xs (y:ys)
                            in if (length lcs1) > (length lcs2)
                                  then lcs1
                                  else lcs2
```

Comment: `String` is just a type alias for `[Char]`. I don't understand your problem.

Comment: my problem, I read this string from a file and need to pass it as an example for this code
lcsList :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
lcsList [] _ = []
lcsList _ [] = []
lcsList (x: xs) (y: ys) = if x == y
                           then x: xs ys lcsList
                           else
                             let lcs1 lcsList = (x: xs) ys
                                 lcs2 lcsList = xs (y: ys)
                             in if (length lcs1)> (length lcs2)
                                   then lcs1
                                   else lcs2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rough and ready way to split out each of those strings is with something like this - which you can try in ghci

```
let a = "Individuo A; TACGATCAAAGCT"
tail $ dropWhile (/= ' ') $ dropWhile (/= ';') a
```

which gives you:

```
"TACGATCAAAGCT"
```

And since a String is just a list of Char, this is the same as:

```
['T', 'A', 'C', 'G', ...
```

Answer (score 3):

If your file consists of several lines, it is quite simple: you just need to skip everything until you find “;”. If your file consists of just one line, you’ll have to look for sequences’ beginnings and endings separately (hint: sequence ends with space). Write a recursive function to do the task, and use functions `takeWhile`, `dropWhile`.

A `String` is already a list of `Char` (it is even defined like this: `type String = [Char]`), so you don’t have to do anything else. If you need a list of `String`s, where every `String` consists of just one char, then use `map` to wrap every char (once again, every `String` is a list, so you are allowed to use `map` on these). To wrap a char, there are three alternatives:

1. Use lambda function: `map (\c -> [c]) s`
2. Use operator section: `map (:[]) s`
3. Define a new function: `wrap x = [x]`

Good luck!